# How to translate "to sleep his way up"?

Tags: значения

I tried to find meaning or translation in dictionaries ,  just failed. Is that means "проспать дорогу на верх"?

So what is the translatoion of "to sleep his way up"?

Original sentence: Chistoff has decided to sleep his way up the corporate ladder.

Comment: This is a question about English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

**In Russian this means**

> **`"Получить повышение (по карьерной лестнице) через постель"`**

Previously I answered with the text below, but this was discussed with @KCd and we decided that it's not correct.

*I think it's probably a typo and most likely that was as `"Chistoff has decided to`<s>**`slip`**</s>`his way up the corporate ladder."` which means*

> *<s>`"забраться вверх по карьерной лестнице"`</s>.*

*Literally it's translated as <s>`"проскользнуть по карьерной лестнице наверх"`</s>. It's acceptable, but more often <s>`"забраться"`</s> or <s>`"проскочить"`</s> are used.*

Comment: Cant be mistake, translation of "to slip his way up" is kind of obvious. Any other ideas?))

Comment: In English nobody talks about slipping their way up the corporate ladder, but sleeping your way up the corporate ladder is a known (if not exactly professional) activity.

Comment: @KCd what the kind of activity is this in English?

Comment: It means sleeping with people who have higher positions of authority. Needless to say, the main activity is in a bed but is not actual sleeping... ясно?

Comment: @KCd oh this, okay it's clear now. Would you like me to include and fix this in the answer or you will write your own answer?

Comment: @KCd in Russian this means `"Получить повышение(по карьерной лестнице) через постель"`

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov: you should fix your answer (but make it clear it's an edit).

Comment: @KCd done and thanks for your contribution.